# Strange determinant inequality $\det(C+ xA) \det(C-xA) \le (\det C)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, determinants

Let $A$ be an all-one $3$-by-$3$ matrix, let $C$ be a $3$-by-$3$ matrix, and let $x$ be a real number. How might one prove the following inequality?

$$\det(C+ xA) \det(C-xA) \le (\det C)^2$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: The matrix determinant Lemma should work if A=J ( J a traditional name for the order n matrix $1*1^t$ with $1$ here being the column vector of all components 1), but requires C being invertible.  Do you have that condition on C? (Otherwise you may need the adjugate form.)  Gerhard "Is Worried About Positive LHS" Paseman, 2018.01.27.

Comment: As suggested above, denoting by $v$ the column vector of all ones, $\det(C+xvv^t)=\det(C)+xv^t \mathrm{adj}(A) v$, and $\det(C-xvv^t)=\det(C)-xv^t \mathrm{adj}(A) v$, so the product is $\det(C)^2-(xv^t adj(A) v)^2\le\det(C)^2$.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Shouldn't it be the adjugate of $C$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes of course, well spotted! Thank you

Comment: @GerhardPaseman If you can prove the inequality for invertible $C$, then by a continuity argument it can be extended to all $C$.